# What is the advantage of using Digital Signature Standard over other Digital Signature Schemes?

Tags: digital-signature

From what I understand, the digital signature standard (DSS) makes use of an additional global public key at signing and verification end, along with the sender's private and public key respectively as usual. 
By doing this, we can achieve Authentication(key involvement) and Integrity(hash function involvement).

The same seems to be achieved using other schemes, so why is DSS the standard? What advantage does it offer over the others?

Comment: Do you mean the DIGITAL SIGNATURE STANDARD (DSS) from the NIST in FIPS PUB  186-4? And to which "other Digital Signature Schemes" do you want to compare it?